# String estática sendo criada com encode errado

Tags: java, string, utf-8, encode

Ola,

Ao criar uma string numa classe Java (por exemplo: `String t = "Ola Java!"`), parece que o compilador está escolhendo o encode 'errado' para interpretar os bytes que estão no fonte e gerar a String (o encode 'certo' deveria ser `UTF-8`, que é o encode que estou usando nos fontes).

Para exemplificar o erro, fiz o seguinte teste:

```
String t = "ã";
log.debug("t: " + t);
log.debug("t.length(): " + t.length());
log.debug("t.getBytes().length: " + t.getBytes().length);
log.debug("t.getBytes(utf-8).length: " + t.getBytes("utf-8").length);
log.debug("t.getBytes(UTF-8).length: " + t.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
log.debug("t.getBytes(ISO-8859-1).length: " + t.getBytes("ISO-8859-1").length);
```

(o mecanismo de log que uso é o `commons-logging` com `log4j` de suporte, mas da para fazer o mesmo usando o `System.out`)

O resultado foi o seguinte:

```
t: Ã£
t.length(): 2
t.getBytes().length: 4
t.getBytes(utf-8).length: 4
t.getBytes(UTF-8).length: 4
t.getBytes(ISO-8859-1).length: 2
```

A primeira linha poderia ser explicada por algum problema de conversão ao converter a string na hora de escrever o arquivo de log.
Porém as demais linhas deixam bem claro o problema.
Já na segunda linha (`t.length()`) da para ver que a String foi criada com dois caracteres, e não um, já mostrando que na criação da string os dois bytes que representam o caractere ã em `utf-8` foram tratados como dois caracteres (em algum outro formato tipo ISO-8859-1).

Estou procurando alguma forma de forçar o encode na interpretação de uma string estática pelo compilador, mas não acho que seja um bom caminho... existe alguma forma de fazer isso? Ou de indicar para o compilador qual o encode deve ser usado ao interpretar as strings estáticas nos fontes
?

Comment: Ok, resolvi o problema. Existe uma opção no compilador para forçar o encode que o mesmo trata os arquivos. A opção é: -encoding (tem também na task javac do ant). Colocando o valro utf-8, funcionou. Pelo jeito, o compilador utiliza o padrão do SO para seu padrão, e não o padrão adota nos classes (UTF-8)... nada como colocar a pergunta por escrito para ter uma nova visão da mesma!

Comment: Adiciona a sua solução como resposta para a pergunta...

Comment: OK, farei isso mais tarde. No momento estou sendo escurraçado  para ir num churrasco!...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da documentação do `javac`:

> **-encoding** *encoding*
>
> Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If
>   **-encoding** is not specified, the platform default converter is used.

Ou seja, se não for especificado explicitamente, o compilador usará o padrão do sistema. Se você pensar bem, isso faz algum sentido: esse é o charset que os editores usam por default, e é o charset que as aplicações Java usam por default -- e o javac é uma aplicação Java.

Naturalmente, especificar `-enconding` na linha de comando resolve. Se você estiver usando algum sistema de build (ant, maven, gradle, etc), especifique essa opção para garantir que os arquivos vão ser tratados da mesma forma em qualquer plataforma.

Se não estiver usando um sistema de build (deveria! :), você pode usar a variável de ambiente `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, colocando algo como, por exemplo, `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` nela.

Por fim, existe uma forma de transformar seus arquivos, qualquer que seja o encoding deles, em ASCII. Junto com o JDK vem um programa chamado `native2ascii`. Esse programa vai converter o arquivo do encoding do sistema, ou um encoding que você especifique com `-encoding`, em um arquivo ASCII usando a sintaxe `\uxxxx` para representar quaisquer caracteres especiais. Por exemplo:

```
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:debug-service dsobral$ cat Teste.java 
class Teste {
    public String test = "Teste de codificação"
}
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:debug-service dsobral$ native2ascii Teste.java
class Teste {
    public String test = "Teste de codifica\u00e7\u00e3o"
}
```

No caso, como não especifiquei o arquivo de saída, ele jogou para a console. Nunca cheguei realmente a usar esse programa (eu uso sistemas de build! :), mas em testes simples ele parece aceitar que o arquivo de saída seja o mesmo de entrada, mas eu faria experimentos com arquivos grandes antes de confiar nisso.

Comment: Interessante esse native2ascii! Não sei se vou usar algum dia, mas é bom saber que existe algo assim... obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Era realmente um problema ao compilar os fontes.

O javac estava considerando que todos os arquivos fonte estavam num mesmo encode, diferente de utf-8. Talvez por padrão o javac utilize o encode padrão do SO.

Para resolver o problema, utilizei a opção -encoding do javac, que permite definir qual o encode deve ser considerado ao ler os fontes (a mesma opção existe na task javac do ant).